# Lauch screen edits not working on any of my iPhone apps using latest Xcode & iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, launch

I wanted to change my Launch Screen image in two of my apps but have encountered the same problem with both apps,  I deleted the image originally used in the Assets folder and replaced it with my new image that I want to be displayed on startup, I made sure I had the correct image selected in the launch screen storyboard but when I run the app I still get the original image showing up.  I deleted the image completely and uploaded the one i wish to use this time with a different name just in case this had been an issue but still i have the same problem.

I deleted the image again and this time also deleted Launch Screen.storyboard and added a new one add my image view as before then upload the image I want to use again and select it in Attributes Inspector but now when I run the app I get a black launch screen.

Comment: Not exactly the same thing - I only updated a single image - but have you *deleted* the app from your device (or at least deleted Derived Data for the simulator)? These helped for me.

Comment: I have unfortunately with the same results

Comment: I can approve that every time this happened to me, delete the app solve the problem

Comment: "but now when i run the app i get a black launch screen" Nearly always caused by the Launch Screen setting in the Info.plist not correctly matching the name of your launch screen storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://openradar.appspot.com/24618582). The problem does not affect builds distributed through the app store in production.

The work around for a debug build is to delete the app, restart the device, and run it fresh. It appears to be a problem with the way images are cached by Springboard based on your bundle identifier.

Comment: Hi @Dare Your solution worked. I even had to do this for my versions that were uploaded to the AppStore. Once I deleted the apps, restarted my device and downloaded the apps again the proper Launch Screens appeared. Thank you